# Debug Pandas Dataframe Apply

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, dataframe, apply

New to Pandas and I have the following question: 
I want to apply my_func (a custom created function) to each row of a dataframe.

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x, par1, par2)
```

When I debug and I put a breakpoint on the first row of my function defined as:

```
def my_func(myinput, par1):
    (...)
```

if I evaluate my input variable myinput I will get the entire dataframe (df).
I was expecting only the first row of df instrad.. Am I missing something?

Many thanks

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `axis=1` in `apply`:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x, par1, par2), axis=1)
```

The [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) states that `axis=0` is column-wise whilst `axis=1` is row-wise

You could just pass the row in:

```
res = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row), axis=1)
```

and then redefine your function:

```
def my_func(row):
    # do something with col1
    row['col1'] = row['col1'] * 2
    row['col2'] = row['col2'] + 2
    # .... etc
```

Comment: If you're only passing in the row, you can just do `df.apply(my_func, axis=1)`. Atlernatively, you can use the `args` kwarg or a `lambda` to  pass in more arguments. `apply(my_funx, axis=1, args=(par1, par2))` or `apply(lambda row: my_func(row, par1, par2), axis=1)`